# CSS Grid - Why there is a leftover space when fr units are less than 0.15?

Tags: css, css-grid

While defining a CSS grid layout, I happened to define the grid rows as follows i:

`grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 0.14fr)`

This led to some confusing behavior, where the grid refused to distribute the remaining space fully; instead, there was some leftover space right at the end.

[image]

I tried the same thing, but using columns this time:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 0.14fr)`

[image]

This resulted in the same behavior. Next, I changed the values as follows, increasing the *0.14fr* to *0.15fr*:

`grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 0.15fr)`

[image]

This made things alright again. Just to make sure that it wasn't issues on my side that was making things weird, I set up the same situation in Codepen: [Weird CSS Grid - pen](https://codepen.io/SphoorthyLA/pen/yLBGvaM).

As the problem repeated itself, I opened up Codepen on Chrome to see if it was browser-specific: it wasn't. The same thing happened again. I've attached the bare-bones code of what I've been trying to do below, with the *fr* units set up to be *0.9fr*, just to make the difference clearer.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;

  /* ----------  Weird stuff starts here ---------- */

  /*   grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 0.15fr); */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 0.09fr);

  /* ----------  Weird stuff ends here ---------- */

}

.box .temp:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

.box .temp:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>
```

**Is this a bug, a machine-specific issue, an innocent little quirk, just how CSS-Grid works and calculates *fr* units or is this a browser-specific issue?**

> Note:
>
> 1. My primary browser is Firefox, but I've tried replicating this in Chrome too.
> 2. Since the browser calculates the widths of the *fr* on-the-go, there might be a chance that this might be reproducible only on my
>      machine. (I think? Not sure.)
> 3. This might be a fringe case, I agree. Why define *fr* units using smaller numbers like below when I can just use numbers bigger than
>      *0.15*, or *1*, really? I only came across this problem (quirk?) when I just typed in the fractional values of a layout; I worked out the
>      *fr* values by dividing the pixel lengths of the child elements by the pixel length of the parent container, which obviously works out to be lesser than 1.
> 4. I used CSS rather than SASS in the pen, since I thought maybe the SASS pre-processor might be doing something weird behind the scenes (far-fetched, I know, but I didn't want to take the chance.)
> 5. The breakpoint between *0.14fr* and *0.15fr* might be specific just to my machine.

Comment: `7*0.14 = 0.98 < 1` while `7*0.15 = 1.05 > 1`

Comment: ^ You are missing 0.02fr which the space you see

Comment: and  `7*0.09 = 0.63`, now it's pretty clear why you are missing 37% of the area

Comment: will add answer to better explain

Comment: @TemaniAfif That makes sense intuitively, but I'm not really sure WHY it makes sense to me, if I'm being honest. I guess this is because I'm not clear on how the Grid calculates fr units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `repeat(7,0.14fr)` it means that you will take from the grid `7*0.14fr = 0.98fr`. Note how you are missing `0.02` to have the `1` and this is the space you are missing.

When defining `repeat(7,0.15fr)` it means you will take `7*0.15fr = 1.05fr`. In this case you are covering all the area and even more but there is no *more*.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit):

> Each column or row’s share of the leftover space can be computed as the column or row’s `<flex> * <leftover space> / <sum of all flex factors>`.
>
> Note: If the sum of the flex factors **is less than 1**, they’ll take up only a **corresponding fraction of the leftover space**, rather than expanding to fill the entire thing. This is similar to how Flexbox [CSS-FLEXBOX-1] acts when the sum of the flex values is less than 1.

If we have a sum less than 1 then each item will take the correspending space. In the first case it's `0.14fr` (`0.14* Height`) and when the sum is bigger than 1 we apply the formula and in this case whataver the value you will be using in `repeat(7,x)` you will have:

```
(x/7*x) * Height = Height/7
```

Basically, you simply divide by 7.

In your case you have two ranges: from `0` to `1/7 = 0.1428..` where you will have missing space. Then above `1/7` where you will not:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-grid;
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, var(--x));


}

.box .temp:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

.box .temp:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--x:0.05fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--x:0.1fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--x:0.14fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="--x:0.1429fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--x:10fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--x:100fr">
  <div class="temp temp--1"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--2"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--3"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--4"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--5"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--6"></div>
  <div class="temp temp--7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This means that if the sum of the flex factors is **less than 1**, the fr units basically behave like **percentage units**?

Comment: @SphoorthyNutulapati kind of, which is logical. If you say `0.5fr` then you want only 50% of the free space and you will have 50% of empty space. Using bigger value than 1 make sense when  using **different** values ... like one is taking `3fr` and the other `2fr` (which is the same as saying `0.6fr` and `0.4fr`). If it's the same value, all the `xfr` are the same if x is bigger than 1